# Join two tables and get count of one but all results matching ID on other

Tags: mysql, sql, count, where-clause, correlated-subquery

This sounds a bit confusing, but it's actually easy.

In one table I store events (like parties).

Example:

| USERID | EventName | EVENTID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | CoolEvent | 0 |
| 10 | MediocreEvent | 1 |

And another table stores invites to that party. Those can have a different status, like "accepted" or "host"  (or "declined" and so on).

Example:

| EVENTID | status |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | accepted |
| 0 | host |
| 0 | declined |

Basically, I need to get all events from one USERID, but also I want to know how many people have either accepted to that event or are the host.

So if I want to find out what events the user with the ID 10 has the result should be:

{EVENTID: 0, EventName: CoolEvent, Count(status == accepted OR host): 2}

{EVENTID: 1, EventName: MediocreEvent, Count(status == accepted OR host): 0}

So two results in total.

This has to happen in one single query.

Can you help me here?

I tried:

```
var sqlString = "SELECT a.name, a.venueAdresse, a.userID, a.tblEventID, a.venueCity, a.startTimeAndDateUnixTicks, a.displayStartTime, a.slots, a.eventPictureThumb, COUNT(b.status) \
FROM 10561_12865_tblEvents a \
RIGHT JOIN 10561_12865_tblInvites b ON (a.tblEventID = b.tblEventID) \
WHERE a.userID  = '" + userID + "'\
AND (b.status = 'accepted' OR b.status = 'host') \
ORDER BY createdUnixInt DESC \
LIMIT " + start + "," + count
```

But this will only return results where ID matches AND status is either accepted or host, but I just want to count the occurrences from one table. So basically the AND just refers to the count property.

So I am a bit stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT e.name, e.venueAdresse, e.userID, e.tblEventID, e.venueCity, e.startTimeAndDateUnixTicks, e.displayStartTime, e.slots, e.eventPictureThumb, 
       (
         SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM `10561_12865_tblInvites` i
         WHERE i.tblEventID = e.tblEventID AND (i.status = 'accepted' OR i.status = 'host')
       ) counter
FROM `10561_12865_tblEvents` e 
WHERE e.userID  = ? 
ORDER BY e.createdUnixInt DESC 
LIMIT ?
```

Replace the `?` placeholders with the parameters that you pass.

Comment: you sir are a gentleman and a scholar! would you care to explain the query a bit though? :)

Answer (score 0):

SET sql_mode = (
SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', '')
);

SELECT t.EventName, t.EVENTID, t.Status, count(Status)
FROM (SELECT e.EventName, e.EVENTID, i.Status FROM event_table e
LEFT JOIN invite_table i
ON e.EVENTID = i.EVENTID) AS t
GROUP BY t.EVENTID, t.Status

Comment: Please add some description to your answer. Also mark code (sql) as sql markdown.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).